# Find gaps in mysql datetime sequence

Tags: mysql, sql, join, timestamp

I have `myTable` with `timestamp` column `the_dates` (which is a `unique` index), and each value SHOULD be separated by five minutes.

For example:

```
the_dates
2014-03-13 17:30:00
2014-03-13 17:35:00
2014-03-13 17:40:00
2014-03-13 17:45:00
```

Is there a way, using mysql, to detect a "missing"  row? For example if the next value was:

```
2014-03-13 17:55:00
```

then `myTable` would be missing:

```
2014-03-13 17:50:00
```

__

I was thinking of using `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` and detecting gaps larger than 300 seconds, perhaps using some sort of `INNER JOIN` to `join` the table to itself, but I'm too much of a novice to pull this off alone.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this.  Each record returned should a time range that exceeds 5 minutes. For your example, it should have returned `2014-03-13 17:45:00 , 2014-03-13 17:55:00`

```
SELECT t1.the_dates AS `from`, t2.the_dates AS `to`
FROM mytable AS t1
JOIN mytable AS t2
  ON t1.the_dates < t2.the_dates
LEFT JOIN mytable AS t3
  ON t3.the_dates > t1.the_dates 
   AND t3.the_dates < t2.the_dates
WHERE t3.the_dates IS NULL
  AND t2.the_dates > DATE_ADD(t1.the_dates, INTERVAL 5 MINUTE)
ORDER BY t1.the_dates;
```

Comment: Thanks I'll play around with this and report back. I might end up having to pull it into some server side script to fill in the gaps regardless

Comment: So, this worked. But it incredibly expensive. Took 21 secs in a table of 650 rows. I'm using a interval of 1 day instead. Could that be any faster somehow?

Comment: @PatrickBassut - Is there an index on the date field? This solution is relatively generic. Can you personalize the implementation? For instance, the LEFT JOIN's purpose to ensure the T2 record is the "next" record. Can you more efficiently JOIN to the subsequent row?

Answer (score 0):

back on the same issue, I tested the proposed solution on a large data set and it's too time consuming.
I tried another approach by embedding request on same table but on next available time :

```sql
SELECT 
    t.id,
    t.`timestamp`,
    (
        SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(t1.`timestamp`)-UNIX_TIMESTAMP(t.`timestamp`) 
        FROM mytable AS t1 
        WHERE t1.timestamp>t.timestamp 
        ORDER BY t1.timestamp ASC LIMIT 1
    ) AS difftime
FROM 
    `mytable ` AS t 
    HAVING difftime > 300
    ORDER BY t.`timestamp` ASC
```

On a table approx 1.2M records, filtering on a specific set of 3500 items, query took 3.5s